# How does one match the file extension using re in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I would like to match any file with `.Mp4` extension. The code does not seem to work as I thought...Any leads??

```
import re

ext=r"\.Mp4$"
files = ["Good cool music yes.Mp4", "Very cool audio.mp3", "Top of the toppest.Mp4"]


for f in files:
    if re.match(ext, f): 
        print(f)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: You need `re.search` not `re.match`. Check the documentation to see the difference.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM is right. See the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see is that you are using re.match() which only checks the beginning of the string for matches regardless of the '$' flag you were passing. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match for more info on search vs match.

Changing your code to search returns the expected results:

```
import re

ext=r"\.mp4$"
files = ["Good cool music yes.Mp4", "Very cool audio.mp3", "Top of the toppest.Mp4"]


for f in files:
    if re.search(ext, f, flags=re.I): 
        print(f)
    else:
        pass
```